# Implement GUI in Function in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I wrote a function that takes `image_id` as input from the user and displays that image to the GUI.

But the problem is that I cannot link my GUI to my function:

- My function is working.
- I can create my GUI using the GUI Builder (and I will want to add more components to it)

Any ideas for the way to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class SI  extends MainMenu {

     BufferedImage image=null ;

       final JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                Graphics g2 = g.create();
                g2.drawImage(image, 3, 0,560,815,null);
                g2.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            }
       };

     public void  ImageReader(String image_id) throws IOException {  
     {  
        ////// To Read Tiff File /////////////////
         MainMenu mm= new MainMenu();
         mm.MainMenu();

         String TifFileReadPath="C:/BILAL/SearchImage/"+image_id+".TIF";  
         File inputFile = new File(TifFileReadPath);

         image= ImageIO.read(inputFile);  
         JFrame2.add(panel);
     }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       SI si = new SI ();
       //String input = getTextfield().getText();

      MainMenu m = new MainMenu();
      String input= m.GetTextFiled();

      si.ImageReader(input);
     }
}
```